# VBA Select visible range in filtered list based upon selection and pre-determined columns

Tags: vba, excel

I assume there is a simple solution for this, but I have been unable to figure it out.

I have a filtered list which I am trying to copy and paste the visible rows I have selected to another worksheet. I am pasting in two separate blocks, so I can't paste the whole row at a time.

[image: Example Table]

I am working with something like this. I have several rows selected, and I want to run this macro to copy A1150:E1197, grabbing only the visible rows, and then copy F1150:L1197. It would be best if it did not require E to be the column selected.

My initial design used a for each loop. For each individual row, it copied the left block, switched to the other worksheet and pasted, rinse and repeat for the right block. It ended up being very slow, taking about 15 seconds for 10 rows or so. I believe switching between the workbooks was the major portion that slowed things down, so I am now trying to copy the left and right blocks each in one go.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: please paste your code  so we can analyze through it

Comment: I made a little mockup where I filled in `A2:A11` and then filtered out all but the first and last row. using `Range("A2:A11").Copy Destination:=Range("A15")`, it only copied the visible cells, so this might be an option for you. The good thing is that in the "Destination" you can specify a different sheet's range

Comment: you might also consider `Range("").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to select only visible cells, but i'm rather sure the previous method i mentioned will already work

Comment: I can post my code if you want, but I'm not sure that gets you anything. I have working code that is very slow. I am trying to go in a different direction to speed things up, but I have this design problem in that I don't know if there is a way to do what I want. 

From the picture I have above, I would like code which would allow me to select A1150:E1197, copy it over, and then do the same thing with F1150:L1197.

Comment: did you try my suggestions?

Comment: Marcucciboy2 I didn't think copy was what I was looking for, but it worked!
Thanks! I will post an answer using your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Marcucciboy2 for the suggestion.

Here is the code I used to copy the left block, then just different columns for the right block.

```
Private Function CopyBlocks()
Dim firstRow As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer

firstRow = ActiveCell.row
lastRow = ActiveCell.row + Selection.Rows.Count - 1

'copy left block
Range("A" & firstRow, "E" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

'Switch workbooks & paste
'copy right block
'switch workbooks and paste

End Function
```